# How to Flip and Rotate image in C# Windows 8.1 Store App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I am trying to flip and rotate image in C# (for Windows Store App).
And it becomes complicated if I try to flip image which is rotated first by some angle say x.

I see

```
Image.RotateFlip
```

method is available only in for Dektop apps.

Is there any existing API that can help in this situation? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Use a CompositeTransform, along with a storyboard to animate the rotations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on a Windows Store App (in C#), I am assuming that you are using `XAML` for your GUI. If that is the case and you want to perform a rotation, This bit of markup should do it.

For Rotation :

```
 <Image Source="/Assets/Logo.png" >
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
 </Image>
```

For Flipping :

```
<Image Source="/Assets/Logo.png">
  <Image.RenderTransform>
    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
  </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```

If you want to perform an animation, you might want to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15187062/653211) answer.

Comment: Thanks Ashwin for the quick response.
Can you give some idea about flipping the image?
I need to combine both these effects.

Rotation I usually handle using Manipulation Delta
But I need to flip the pre-rotated image now (i.e. flip horizontally or flip vertically - kind of mirror effect)